# PHP Contact Form json empty

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i download a template with bootstrap and the contact form sends the email but the content is empty and i don´t know why.

This is the HTML Form

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="get" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefono</label>
                        <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Titulo *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Mensaje *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And this is the sendmail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'<b>Gracias por contactarnos. Nos comunicaremos con usted lo antes posible</b> '
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'my@email.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Nombre: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Tema: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Mensaje: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'De: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;

?>
```

I dont know why is not working, please i need help with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: using form method get and getting values from $_POST ??????

Comment: i changed to post and i doesn´t work either

Comment: print_r($_POST); check values, if getting means, u need to configure smtp